# How do I test a file upload in rails for integration testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, fixtures

I do some integration testing like this :

```
 def user.excel_import
          fixture_excel = fixture_file_upload('goodsins.xls', 'text/xls')
          post excel_import_goods_ins_goods_ins_path, :dump=> {:excel_file=>fixture_excel}, :html => { :multipart => "true" }
          assert_response :redirect
          assert_redirected_to goods_ins_path
       end
```

But when I run the testing it is said that : goodsins.xls file does not exist.
FYI : I put the file in the folder that named fixtures.

Any idea? Thx u very much

Comment: This kind of test is traditionally called controller test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The notes here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload indicate that you need to include a slash before the path or file name.

try `fixture_file_upload('/goodsins.xls', 'text/xls')` and see if that helps.

fixture_file_upload Source:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb, line 523
def fixture_file_upload(path, mime_type = nil, binary = false)
  if ActionController::TestCase.respond_to?(:fixture_path)
    fixture_path = ActionController::TestCase.send(:fixture_path)
  end

  ActionController::TestUploadedFile.new("#{fixture_path}#{path}",
    mime_type, binary)
end
```

Update from Question Owner:

Solution:

add `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` to `test_helper.rb`

Comment: yup I have already use the slash before the path or file name, but it is stillfile does not exist .... on functional testing it works well, but on integration testing it is not working ...

Comment: But ur link is very usefull for me ... thx for me ... the solution is just add this include ActionDispatch::TestProcess to the following test_helper.rb